# How do I export regular class or enum from my angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have two libraries, `mat-text-editor` and `mat-text-editor-select`, the former uses the component of the latter, which works fine. `mat-text-editor-select` also includes a regular typescript class, `mat-text-editor-select-option`, which I want to export alongside the `mat-text-editor-select-component` so I can use it in the `mat-text-editor` module.

I can import the file like this:

```
import { MatTextEditorSelectOption } from "projects/mat-text-editor-select/src/mat-text-editor-select-option";
```

This is recognized but throws an error when I try to build the text-editor library: `File 'D:/Documents/Websites/angular-material-extension/projects/mat-text-editor-select/src/mat-text-editor-select-option.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'D:\Documents\Websites\angular-material-extension\projects\mat-text-editor\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

I've added `export * from './mat-text-editor-select-option';` to the public-api.ts of the `mat-text-editor-select` library and tried to import the class like this:

```
import { MatTextEditorSelectOption } from "mat-text-editor-select/mat-text-editor-select-option";
```

but VS Code complains it cannot find the module. I've also tried:

```
import { MatTextEditorSelectOption } from "mat-text-editor-select";
```

but it says mat-text-editor-select has no exported member named MatTextEditorSelectOption, which I'm surprised because shouldn't it have now? What else do I need to do to export/import the class from one library to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an exported regular typescript class is part of the package, but not of the module, thus I couldn't import the class from the `mat-text-editor` library by targeting the module. You need to target the package, i.e. the one in the dist folder after building the exported library.

Instead of:

```
import { MatTextEditorSelectOption } from "mat-text-editor-select/mat-text-editor-select-option";
```

You have to write:

```
import { MatTextEditorSelectOption } from "dist/mat-text-editor-select/mat-text-editor-select-option";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the two components in the library’s module

Comment: There is only one component, which I already am exporting. I can use the `MatTextEditorSelectComponent` perfectly fine. The other is not a component, it's just a regular typescript class, that I want to export as well. That's what I've written, please read the question.

Comment: Can you add some code of where you do the exporting?

Comment: What exporting are you talking about? I've created the library with angular CLI, it automatically creates a component and a module file and writes the export code of the component into the module. The question is, how do I export a regular class, not a component.

Comment: I've already written this: "I've added export * from './mat-text-editor-select-option'; to the public-api.ts" That's where I do the export.